Texture paint python script?
I am using MPFB to procedurally generate people. I then export a high res XYZ file of their head. Then, I want to place a texture paint on their forehead of a red arrow, and take a photo of it. Currently, I can generate the humans, export the xyz, and export the photo, but I cannot for the life of me figure out the texture paint. I keep getting context errors, and I can't find the source code to edit it.
Other things I have tried:

Creating a cloth plane and having gravity pull it onto the forehead: This doesn't work because it is colliding with the underlying model, not the procedurally generated one from MPFB

Placing the image above the head and down projecting every pixel: For some reason this is not pasting the color onto the head


I need proportions to be maintained in the final image, which is why I am not just applying this to every UV mapped skin option.
Relevant code that I have tried:
For down projecting:
    def move_image():
        """
        Moves the 'image' object to center it on the 'PaintArea' vertex group,
        accounting for all modifiers and transformations.
        Only updates X and Y coordinates, preserving Z height.
        """
        
    # Get the human and image objects
        human = bpy.data.objects['Human']
        img = bpy.data.objects['image']
        
        
    # Get the evaluated mesh data that includes all modifiers and deformations
        depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
        eval_human = human.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
        mesh = eval_human.data
        
        
    # Get vertex group
        vertex_group = human.vertex_groups['PaintArea']
        
        
    # Get vertices in vertex group from evaluated mesh
        vertices = []
        
    for
     v 
    in
     mesh.vertices:
            
    for
     g 
    in
     v.groups:
                
    if
     g.group == vertex_group.index:
                    
    # Transform vertex position to world space
                    world_pos = eval_human.matrix_world @ v.co
                    vertices.append(world_pos)
        
        
    if
     not vertices:
            print("No vertices found in PaintArea group")
            
    return
            
        
    # Calculate center of vertex group in world space
        center = Vector((0, 0, 0))
        
    for
     v 
    in
     vertices:
            center += v
        center /= len(vertices)
        
        
    # Move image to center position, preserving original Z coordinate
        img.location.x = center.x
        img.location.y = center.y
        
    # Z coordinate remains unchanged
    
    def project_point_onto_mesh(
    point
    , 
    target_obj
    , 
    direction
    ):
        """
        Projects a point in a direction onto a target mesh.
        
        Args:
            point (Vector): Starting point for the projection
            target_obj: The target mesh object to project onto
            direction (Vector): Direction vector for the projection
            
        Returns:
            Vector or None: Hit location in world space, or None if no hit
        """
        ray_start = 
    point
        ray_end = 
    point
     + 
    direction
     * 1000.0
        
        hit, location, normal, index, obj, matrix = bpy.context.scene.ray_cast(
            bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph,
            ray_start,
            
    direction
        )
        
        
    return
     location
    
    def project_image_onto_mesh():
        """
        Projects an image onto a mesh and colors the projected points on the mesh.
        Projects straight downward (-Z) from the image object onto the Human mesh.
        """
        mesh_obj = bpy.data.objects['Human']
        img_obj = bpy.data.objects['image']
        image_position = img_obj.location
        image_width = img_obj.dimensions.x
        image_height = img_obj.dimensions.y
        paint_color = (1, 0, 0, 1)  
    # Red color
        direction = Vector((0, 0, -1))
        
        print(f"Image position: {image_position}")
        print(f"Image dimensions: width={image_width}, height={image_height}")
    
        
    # Create or get vertex color layer
        
    if
     "Col" not in mesh_obj.data.vertex_colors:
            mesh_obj.data.vertex_colors.new(
    name
    ="Col")
        color_layer = mesh_obj.data.vertex_colors["Col"]
        
        
    # Get evaluated mesh
        depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
        eval_mesh = mesh_obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph).data
        
        colored_vertices = set()
    
        width = bpy.data.images['arrow.png'].size[0]
        height = bpy.data.images['arrow.png'].size[1]
        
        print(f"Using resolution: {width}x{height}")
        
        
    # Calculate step sizes in world space
        step_x = image_width / width
        step_y = image_height / height
        
        
    # Project from each pixel
        
    for
     i 
    in
     range(width):
            
    for
     j 
    in
     range(height):
                
    # Convert pixel coordinates to world space
                x = image_position.x - image_width/2 + (i * step_x)
                y = image_position.y - image_height/2 + (j * step_y)
                point = Vector((x, y, image_position.z))
                
                hit_location = project_point_onto_mesh(point, mesh_obj, direction)
                
    if
     hit_location:
                    
    # Find closest vertices to hit point
                    
    for
     poly 
    in
     eval_mesh.polygons:
                        
    for
     loop_index 
    in
     poly.loop_indices:
                            vertex_idx = eval_mesh.loops[loop_index].vertex_index
                            
    if
     vertex_idx not in colored_vertices:
                                vertex = eval_mesh.vertices[vertex_idx]
                                vertex_world = mesh_obj.matrix_world @ vertex.co
                                
    if
     (vertex_world - hit_location).length < step_x:  
    # Use pixel size as radius
                                    color_layer.data[loop_index].color = paint_color
                                    colored_vertices.add(vertex_idx)
        
        print(f"Colored {len(colored_vertices)} vertices")
        
        
    # Update the viewport
        mesh_obj.data.update()


For texture painting (sorry it's commented out):

    # def apply_mark_with_world_space():
    #     # Get the active object
    #     obj = bpy.context.active_object
    #     if not obj:
    #         print("No active object")
    #         return
    
    #     # Store current mode and switch to texture paint
    #     original_mode = obj.mode
    #     bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='TEXTURE_PAINT')
    
    #     try:
    #         # Get or create a single brush instance
    #         brush_name = "ArrowStamp"
    #         if brush_name not in bpy.data.brushes:
    #             brush = bpy.data.brushes.new(name=brush_name, mode='TEXTURE_PAINT')
    #         else:
    #             brush = bpy.data.brushes[brush_name]
                
    #         # Set as active brush
    #         bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.image_paint.brush = brush
    #         bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.unified_paint_settings.size = 10
    
    #         # Configure brush settings
    #         brush.strength = 1.0
    #         brush.color = (1, 0, 0)  # Red color
    
    #         # Find a 3D View area and its region
    #         area = None
    #         region = None
    #         for a in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    #             if a.type == 'VIEW_3D':
    #                 area = a
    #                 region = a.regions[-1]  # Usually the last region is the 3D View
    #                 break
    
    #         if not area:
    #             # If no 3D View is found, temporarily change the current area
    #             original_area_type = bpy.context.area.type
    #             bpy.context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
    #             area = bpy.context.area
    #             region = area.regions[-1]
            
    #         # Create override context
    #         override = bpy.context.copy()
    #         override['area'] = area
    #         override['region'] = region
    #         override['active_object'] = obj
    
    #         # Cast rays and create stroke points
    #         start_point = Vector((0, 0, 1))
    #         end_point = Vector((0, 10, 1))
    #         num_points = 50
            
    #         stroke_points = []
    #         for t in range(num_points):
    #             alpha = t / (num_points - 1)
    #             point = start_point.lerp(end_point, alpha)
                
    #             hit, loc, norm, idx, hit_obj, matrix = bpy.context.scene.ray_cast(
    #                 bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph,
    #                 point,
    #                 Vector((0, 0, -1))
    #             )
                
    #             if hit and hit_obj == obj:
    #                 stroke_points.append({
    #                     "name": "Stroke",
    #                     "mouse": (loc.x, loc.y),
    #                     "pen_flip": False,
    #                     "is_start": (t == 0),
    #                     "location": (loc.x, loc.y, loc.z),
    #                     "pressure": 1.0,
    #                     "time": t
    #                 })
            
    #         # Draw the stroke if we have points
    #         if stroke_points:
    #             bpy.ops.paint.image_paint(override, stroke=stroke_points)
    
    #     finally:
    #         # Restore original mode and area type
    #         bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=original_mode)
    #         if 'original_area_type' in locals():
    #             bpy.context.area.type = original_area_type



Why are you painting it instead of overlaying a texture with blend mode using alpha and flattening or baking it? It just seems easier to arrive at something with a compositor output with python than to try to force the program to texture paint with code that looks more like baking using raycasting. I am not solid enough of a programmer to understand all of this, but surely a composite would be an easier result.

A recent feature of MPFB is the concept of makeup and ink layers. You could use this to place a red arrow on the forehead. See the release notes at https://static.makehumancommunity.org/mpfb/releases/release_20b2.html or the specific docs at https://static.makehumancommunity.org/mpfb/docs/assets/makeup.html
This way you don't need to modify the underlying skin texture and can get away with less complexity than when trying to texture paint.
If you need to script this, you can take a look at the "mpfb.load_library_ink" operator, https://github.com/makehumancommunity/mpfb2/blob/master/src/mpfb/ui/assetlibrary/operators/loadlibraryink.py
I did not test, but you should be able to call this from a python script with something akin to
import bpy
bpy.ops.mpfb.load_library_ink(filepath="/path/to/an/ink_layer_json")

